# How to disable Android Studio network activity after pressing the run button

Tags: android

Every time I press the run app button while connected to the internet Android Studio is sending or fetching something from the internet casing delay while building/compiling the APK file before the app is installed in the device. If I disconnected  the internet while its doing this the app will run immediately. Gradle auto sync is disabled and I press Sync every time after editing dependencies.
Now, writing and testing code in Android Studio is considerably slower while connected to internet. Is there a way to disable this in **Version 3.3.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Gradle offline when building with Android Studio, proceed as follows:

- Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac,
  Android Studio > Preferences).
- In the left pane, click Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.
- Check the Offline work checkbox.
- Click Apply or OK.

[image]

If you're building from the command line, pass the --offline option.

see also

> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build

Comment: What about when I add a new dependency? shouldn't I uncheck it to be able to sync?

Comment: you don't need to unckeck to sync new dependencies

Comment: How? I can't nt do this?

Comment: the same way you check offline work , uncheck the check box offline work to sync new dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Settings(CTRL+ALT+S) -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> Gradle -> Offline work

[image]